# How to resolve dependency problem with version conflicts?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, location, google-play-services

I am using this version `implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0`, but I need to use this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1` or above.

Every time I build, it says all dependencies either should be above or below **14.0.0**. But no version of play-services is available higher than this version 10.2.0 (Not in my knowledge).

And is there any way that I can simply remove this Google play service dependency without getting any error. Because every time I remove it and build it gives this error (see the attached picture).

[image]

Comment: Please refer this :- https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha i did refer this but i cant seem to find any new version of com.google.android.gms:play-services. 
btw Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in app.gradle :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in project gradle:

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```